# RDP From Mac to Windows with FULL keyboard control

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

Hey guys I've become accustomed to controlling my main rig from light laptops using RDP.

Recently got an M1 pro and I've tried MS Remote desktop and Teamviewer and neither seem to be able to pass all keyboard presses to the remote host.

MacOS will always intercept keyboard combinations making it incredibly frustrating.

Eg. Command/Win + Tab should open task view in windows don't eh remote machine but instead takes me out of the RDB session.

This is just one example a LOT of keyboard combinations will not work. Some that work in team viewer (yes I have the send special keys option turned on) but wont work in MS RDP and visa versa.

I've gone through security and given the apps access to everything makes no difference. MacOS will always intercept keyboard shortcuts.

Is there no way to get an effective RDP experience from a Mac?
Happy to try any alternative software or any system hacks you suggest.
(Macbook M1 Pro Monteray OS and Windows 10 pro PC)